# react how to redirect to a page if the user refresh (using f5) in a function component

Tags: reactjs, function, components, f5

redirect to a page

I already tried with the code below, but the alert message never appears, instead the message "reload site ?" is showed

and the redirect is not done

can anyone help me, thanks

```
const handler = useCallback((e) => {
  alert("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
  return true;
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.onbeforeunload = handler;

  return () => {
    window.onbeforeunload = handler;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows, it's not perfect but...

also I put the handler in a class component

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {            
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnloadPage);
    } else {            
        window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', this.onUnloadPage);
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnloadPage);
    } else {
        window.detachEvent('onbeforeunload', this.onUnloadPage);
    }
}

onUnloadPage = (event) => {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = '/collections/';
    }, 0);
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
};
```